A desktop widget that shows which audio output is currently being used
I bind my mouse DPI button to switch audio output. But when I press I don't know which audio output is using. I know you can check it from bottom right corner : Sound Settings.
But I want to see it on Windows desktop as a widget or something. So it will be faster instead of checking from bottom right settings.
Is it even possible?
Actually I did tried nothing. Because I don't know how to do it. Also didn't find any solutions on internet.

The IMMDeviceEnumerator interface should be able to provide the required information. I use it to determine the current default audio device. COM interfaces are cumbersome, but I couldn't find a simpler approach.
